# Issue with maven export and mp3spi

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ to make a Discord bot that can send audio to voice channels (that part works just fine). I am using a library called mp3spi to support playing mp3 files.
Since this program is just for me, I'm using the local repository in maven to add the 3 files needed for mp3spi: `mp3spi1.9.5.jar`, `jl1.0.1.jar`, and `tritonus_share.jar`.

As far as I can tell, these jars are successfully being exported to the output jar when packaged with maven. The problem I'm running into is that trying to play mp3 files throws an UnsupportedAudioFileException. However, in IntelliJ if I just click "Run" to start the program it works just fine.

I've tried looking at solutions to similar problems, but I can't figure out why it works when run from within IntelliJ but not after being packaged with maven. (Even though the libraries appear to be in the output jar)

Comment: Could you please provide the layout of the final jar file? Are the classes from the library jars merged into the single jar file?

Comment: Yes. I checked the output jar and I found the library classes inside. I'm not at my computer at the moment so I can't get anything specific.